# Cron job starts the python script, but no output is received

Tags: usb, python, cron

I have a python program that copies contents of USB devices connected to my pc, in this case it's an Android tablet. The script usese `pyudev` to detect the devices and then use `GVfs` to mount them.

I wanted to start the script and run it in the backgroud, so I don't have to launch it everytime. I tried starting it in `/etc/init/` but running `GVfs` as root causes issues, so I decided to run the script via `cron`. I have it set to start at a specific time, if I do a `ps -aux` and I can see the process listed, however if I plug in my device, nothing happens, the files are not copied.

If I start the script manually, it works without any issues.

This is what I have in my crontab.

`45 10   * * *   cyberbemon      /home/cyberbemon/Development/python/usb-dumper-1.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/usb-dumper/./usb-dumper.py`
`

The python is using this env `#!/usr/bin/env python`

I tried to log the programs output to a file, like so `cyberbemon      /home/cyberbemon/Development/python/usb-dumper-1.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/usb-dumper/./usb-dumper.py > /home/cyberbemon/usb-dumped/log.txt     2>&1`

But that file is empty.

I got the program's source from here: https://codingteam.net/project/usb-dumper/download

Comment: Get rid of `2>&1` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have edited ***yr*** user's crontab, then suppress/erase the user name `cyberbemon` that precedes the long path leading to yr script. You do not need the user's name in there.
- If I am not mistaken you specify the user's environment with `#!` at the beginning, no just `!`. It may just be a typo in post or you forgot to escape the pound sign inside the code block, when writing your post (like so `\#!` ).
  So it should read:

  #!/usr/bin/env python
- It may just be me, but I am not familiar with paths that contain `/./` somewhere in the middle, as in:

> /home/cyberbemon/Development/python/usb-dumper-1.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/usb-dumper/  .  /usb-dumper.py

... without the added spaces. Normally in most type shells `.` is:

- synonym for cmd `source` when used alone before a file name.
- denotes a hidden file, when prefixing a file name.
- is used in regex to match one single character
- indicates the present working directory when used in paths, as for example in

  $ cd $HOME/Desktop; pwd

  /home/cyberbemon/Desktop

  $ cp $HOME/.bashrc .

I would recommend you go to the directory where your Python script is stored and in the terminal run the command `pwd`. You will get the full path to yr script.